# Swift SIMD or Accelerate Sum UInt32

Tags: swift, simd, accelerate-framework

Is there a built-in facility to Accelerate or elsewhere for summing an array of UInt32 using accelerated vector operations?

Comment: As I understand it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567517/sum-array-of-unsigned-8-bit-integers-using-the-accelerate-framework, there is no such function which operates directly on integer arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that you want to accelerate a function such as

```
func scalarsum (_ test_array: [UInt32]) -> UInt32 {
   var result : UInt32 = 0
   for x in test_array {
     result = result &+ x
   }
   return result
}
```

So maybe you can write something complicated such as this...

```
func simdsum (_ test_array: [UInt32]) -> UInt32 {
   var tmpvector=uint4(0)
   // assume test_array.count is divisible by four
   let limit = test_array.count/4
   for i in 0..<limit {
     let thisvector = uint4(test_array[4*i],test_array[4*i+1],test_array[4*i+2],test_array[4*i+3])
     tmpvector = tmpvector &+ thisvector
   }
   return tmpvector[0] + tmpvector[1] + tmpvector[2] + tmpvector[3]
}
```

However, let us look what assembly swift produces for the first function...

`simdsum[0x100001070] <+448>: movdqu 0x20(%rcx,%rdi,4), %xmm2
simdsum[0x100001076] <+454>: movdqu 0x30(%rcx,%rdi,4), %xmm3
(...)
simdsum[0x10000107c] <+460>: paddd  %xmm2, %xmm0
simdsum[0x100001080] <+464>: paddd  %xmm3, %xmm1`

Ah! Ah! Swift is smart enough to vectorize the sum.

So the short answer is that if you are trying to manually design a sum function using SIMD instructions in Swift, you are probably wasting your time... the compiler will do the work for you automagically.

See further code at https://github.com/lemire/Code-used-on-Daniel-Lemire-s-blog/tree/master/extra/swift/simdsum

Comment: The compiler will also vectorize `array.reduce(0, &+)`; I don't think there's really much reason to even write a function. 

(That said, it is possible to handle alignment and edging better than the compiler does; this would yield significant speedups if your array is usually small, at the cost of writing explicit vector code. For typical lengths > 128 or so, the difference will be minimal).

Comment: "I don't think there's really much reason to even write a function." -> Point taken but, of course, this does not contradict what I stated.